# Can't resolve 'ngx-cookie-service/lib/cookie.service'

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

In Angular (ver 10.2) I'm trying to use ngx-cookie-service per instructions:

1. Ran "npm install ngx-cookie-service --save"
2. In app.module.ts, added provider as follows: "providers: [CookieService],"
3. In app.module.ts, imported as follows: "import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service/lib/cookie.service';"

I can use it in the code & no errors shown in any file, so it seems it finds it... but when trying to build "ng build --prod", I get this error:

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-cookie-service/lib/cookie.service'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see the import that you are using is incorrect. It should be:

`import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';`

And you can check it out inside the [library readme](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service#readme).

You've probably copied the code from a demo project inside the library itself and that's why it's not working or maybe the text editor auto generated it, sometimes it happens.

Inside the ngx-cookie-service project it will work because the library is local but in your case it's an external package so you will need to use the [public_api](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/blob/master/projects/ngx-cookie-service/src/public-api.ts).